# select random item from a drop down list in excel

Tags: excel, random

I have an Excel sheet with cells that can be filled only with items from the dropdown list and I want to fill it randomly

[image: Dropdown List]]

Many of the solutions on the web select a random value from a list (not a dropdown list) this does not work for me because my drop-down lists are dependent on other cells so they change based on them what i want is to randomly select items from each new dropdown list

Comment: Are you asking for 1) items in a dropdown (validation) list to be sorted randomly? Or are you 2) looking to select a list at random? Or are you 3) wanting to populate a cell from a randomly selected list item? Or something else?

Comment: The validation for a particular `cell` (eg `Range("A1")`) is specified as as a `Validation` object  provided by the `cell`'s  `Validation` property - `cell.Validation`. For  a cell with a drop-down list the `Formula1` property (ie `cell.Validation.Formula1`) property provides the drop-down values. Programatically, you can select one of these values at random. There is a bit of work involved because the `Formula1` property is returned as a string of whatever was typed into the 'Source:' field of the Data Validation dialog when the drop-down list was specified.

Answer (score 2):

In my example cell A1 has a validation list. When the user selects the cell, it gets a random value from its validation list:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim v As Variant

   If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
      'If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
      If Target.Column = 1 Then  ' all cells in column 1  (A)
         v = getRandomValue(Target, Me)
         If v <> vbNullString And v <> Target.Value2 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value2 = v
            Application.EnableEvents = True
         End If
      End If
   End If
End Sub

' GET A VALUE FROM A RANDOM CELL, OF CELL's VALIDATION LIST
Public Function getRandomValue(r As Range, ws As Worksheet) As Variant
   Dim s As String, ir As Range
   
   getRandomValue = vbNullString
   If hasValidationList(r) Then
      s = Trim(r.Validation.Formula1)
      Set ir = ws.Range(Trim(Mid(s, 2)))
      getRandomValue = ir.Cells(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, ir.CountLarge)).Value2
   End If
End Function

' HELPER FUNCTION - CHECK IF A CELL HAS VALIDATION LIST
Public Function hasValidationList(r As Range) As Boolean
   Dim t As XlDVType

   On Error Resume Next
   t = r.Validation.Type
   On Error GoTo 0
   hasValidationList = (t = xlValidateList)
End Function


' AN EXAMPLE TO FILL ANY CELLS IN A1:A1000 WHITCH HAVE A VALIDATION LIST
' WITH A RANDOM VALUE FROM THEIR LIST

'COPY THIS IN THE SHEET'S MODULE  (NO IN A COMMON MODULE)
Private Sub fillAllCellsRandomly()
   Dim lastRow As Long, rng As Range, rr As Range, v As Variant
   lastRow = 1000
   Set rng = Me.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
   For Each rr In rng
      v = getRandomValue(rr, Me)
      If v <> vbNullString Then rr.Value2 = v
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: how can i use this code and what language is this?

Comment: is VBA for excel applications, what you mean "how can I use? ..."

Comment: thank you so much for everything sir. i have just one question. is this going to fill all the cells in the column automatically?

Comment: My example check only cell  A1 WHEN THE USER SELECT THE CELL, if you want all cells in column A then have to modify the check:  See in the answer...